# "Represented by" vs. "represented with"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, by-with

What should I write?

> - A certain property is represented with a special color.
> - A certain property is represented by a special color.

Or maybe even "indicated with/by"? But the main point of this question remains: *with* or *by*?

Answer (score 10):

You would say it is represented *by* a certain color.

Comment: +1:  Although I wouldn't say "with" is necessarily incorrect... just that "by" is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

With and by signify 2 different meanings:

Consider:

He was represented ***with*** his accomplices ***by*** the best lawyer available.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a difference in meaning.

*by*: something takes the place of and refers to something bigger, e.g., a country is represented by a flag or a team in an international competition.

*with*: an attribute with which something or someone is depicted, e.g., Saint Rita is represented with a bunch of flowers.