# "separated by", "separated with", or does it not matter?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, by-with

I'm describing how you write something down (specifically, an array initializer in JavaScript, but that's not important), and find myself intrigued by the choice of using "separated by" vs. "separated with." I wonder if there are rules, or whether it doesn't really matter which you use.

As a native English speaker (mostly of American English but influenced by British English), my largely unschooled instinct is that "separated by" is more of an observation of fact ("As we can see in the diagram, the entries are separated by commas"), and that "separated with" is more related to an instruction ("When writing...put the entries between the square brackets, separated with commas")... I think part of the reason I feel that tug toward "with" is that I'd *definitely* use "with" in the imperative sentence "Separate the entries with commas."

Is there language logic to back that up? And/or is my unschooled instinct simply wrong? :-)

In this case, I'm primarily interested in informal but professional American English usage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a passive construction with a participle like *separated*, *by* and *with* have different functions.

- ***by*** marks an **agent** phrase: *The fighters were finally separated by the referee.*
- ***with*** marks an **instrumental** phrase: *The fighters were finally separated with a crowbar.*

When you're talking about metaphoric separation -- item boundaries in a left-to-right line -- you have the option of treating the "separator" either as an agent itself, or as a tool (of another agent).

> Interestingly, this is the same range of meanings as the agentive *-er* suffix:
>   a *typewriter* is an instrument, but a *ghostwriter* is a human, and therefore an agent.

- *The entries are separated by commas* is the agent interpretation,
  a passive version of  *Commas separate the entries.*
- *The entries were separated with commas* is the instrument interpretation,
  a passive version of *`Indef` separated the entries with commas.*

Note the different tenses required above; *being separated* is either an event or a state. 
Permanent states normally take present tense (*My car is red* even though it's been red for 5 years). 
Events can be located on the time continuum, usually in the past tense.
So past tense is likely to signal reference to an event, and present tense to a state.

Comment: This is a 50-y-old single malt answer. Sorry, Bourbon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: LOL, almost a year later. Good stuff, Bourbon.

Comment: I've never liked Scotch, but had a 'Black Bush' when trying to avoid pneumonia on the Dingle Peninsula earlier this year. I was so impressed that I've got a couple of bottles in for Christmas. Some day, Catherine and I will go back to see the Dingle Peninsula (most of the rest of the tour was delightful).

Comment: I loved Dingle, but there were a lot of soft days. Want to get back to Ireland sometime; I've only been to the other side once and now I'm a continent and an ocean away. And don't drink much any more, alas.

Comment: (Not sure how I managed not to come back to this for so long.) The commas in the target sentence are instruments, of course, so that probably explains my "with" instinct. Thank you.

Comment: Charles Fillmore pointed out the difference between "The house was destroyed by fire" and "The house was destroyed with fire", the last implying the participation of some agent (the arsonist).

Answer (score 3):

Your use of *with* in this context is entirely appropriate.

[*With*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/with):

> 10. a. By the means or agency of. b. By the presence or use of. (AHDEL)

Some examples of such usage:

> - Items in lists are usually separated *with* commas... (Grammar Monster)
> - How to: Display an Item List Separated *with* Commas - MSDN
> - The nonessential adjective clause (like other nonessential elements) SHOULD be separated *with* commas. (Towson.edu)
> - Nonessential appositives are set off from the rest of the sentence *with* commas. (The Editor's Blog)
> - ...as many different addresses as you want as long as the addresses are separated *with* commas. (cmu.edu)

I think you can feel safe in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/represented-by-vs-represented-with).

The short answer is: **prefer *by* over *with***. It is not that *with* is wrong, but it is commonly used in cases like:

> This was done *with* the help of that.

In most cases *by* and *with* are interchangeable, yet it could vary in cases like:

> I smell *with* <sub>(not by)</sub> my nose.

One of the interchangeable cases is:

> This is indicated *by/with* a green light.

If you are writing documentation for your application, use the correct word for readability. For instance,

> This should be instantiated *by* passing the arguments A, B and C. They should be separated *by* a comma. This should be called *with* D and E.

Comment: It seems to me the linked question is using quite a different sense of "by," it would never occur to me to use "with" in that situation. (I'd even go so far as to say it was wrong.") Whereas the case in my question is much more ambiguous (or so it seems to me). It would be a definite "with" if the sentence were "Separate the entries with commas," for instance.

Comment: Please support your answer with links. That makes your answer stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct (as you will at least have researched it enough to support it). Otherwise it's only opinion.

Answer (score -2):

My knowledge tells me that "by" is mostly used by Americans, and "with" is mostly used by the British.  Otherwise, either word can work.

Comment: What is your knowledge? Please support your answer with links. That makes your answer stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct (as you will at least have researched it enough to support it). Otherwise it's only opinion.